# Installing GHC 7.8.2 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: haskell

First: Yes, I really do mean to install install just GHC, and not the Haskell Platform.  I am installing in a VM made just for this purpose, I have the platform installed elsewhere.

So the [standard instructions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/distribution_packages#ubuntu) for installing from a distro mentions `ghc6` which is not recognized as a valid target (anymore?).  So if I install the `ghc` package instead, I (successfully) get 7.6.3.

I did make sure that I have `universe` enabled, and have the latest package list.  Is it that 7.8.2 is not packaged yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The officially supported version (in other words, the version in the official repos) is 7.6.2 for 13.04 and 7.6.3 for 13.10 and 14.04, according to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ghc) website.

If you wish to use a different version, you can compile it from source or use a PPA that supplies the one you prefer, for example, check out [this](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ghc) PPA. (For more information on PPAs, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) question.)

Comment: Indeed - ghc's own pages are misleading on this point.  Thanks.